# Spring Integration Security with REST service example

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing Spring Integration for REST services. I am following XPadro's githib example - https://github.com/xpadro/spring-integration.

I have created simple read, write and update operations.
Examples taken from `int-http-dsl` project.

I want to implement spring-security with oath2. I am taking reference from http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/security.html.

I am not able to connect both together. Because below is how they map a request

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpGetFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGetGate()).channel("httpGetChannel").handle("personEndpoint", "get").get();
    }
@Bean
    public MessagingGatewaySupport httpGetGate() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway handler = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        handler.setRequestMapping(createMapping(new HttpMethod[]{HttpMethod.GET}, "/persons/{personId}"));
        handler.setPayloadExpression(parser().parseExpression("#pathVariables.personId"));
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper());

        return handler;
    }
```

and below is how we can integrate security

```
@Bean
    @SecuredChannel(interceptor = "channelSecurityInterceptor", sendAccess = "ROLE_ADMIN")
    public SubscribableChannel adminChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

I am not able to find a way to create channels in first example so how to integrate that.

**Am I going right direction or getting it all wrong?**

***Is there any better tutorials to handle spring-integration (http) with spring-security (using oauth)?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration Java DSL allows to use external `@Bean`s for message channels from the flow definition. So, your `httpGetChannel` may be declared and used like:

```
@Bean
@SecuredChannel(interceptor = "channelSecurityInterceptor", sendAccess = "ROLE_ADMIN")
public SubscribableChannel httpGetChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpGetFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGetGate())
                  .channel(httpGetChannel())
                  .handle("personEndpoint", "get")
                  .get();
}
```

Feel free to raise a GitHub issue to make in the Framework something more obvious directly from the DSL's `.channel()` definition: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues

Comment: Can you use this annotation on a Http.inboundGateway?

Comment: What annotation? `@SecuredChannel`? See its purpose: it can be used only on `MessageChannel` beans: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/security.html#securing-channels

Comment: I know you can put Preauthorize along with RequestMapping on a RestController endpoint can you acheive the same on a Http.InboundGateway or IntegrationFlow?

Comment: OK. Doesn't look like your request is relevant somehow to this SO thread. Please, consider to raise a new one with much more info. Doing the chat like this over here confuses community.

Comment: Ok thanks will have a think ... I guess I need to figure out what I want to ask lol